# Postgresql: Trying to Understand the Information Schema Table Constraints Info for a NOT NULL Contstraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, information-schema, notnull

In Postgresql, You can obtain information about the constraints on a table by using a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.table_constraints WHERE table_name='table_name';
```

When I do this, columns that have a NOT NULL constraint will show up something like this:

```
2200_77911989_1_not_null
```

The not_null part is obviously showing a NOT NULL constraint. The last number seems to be the ordinal position of the column. But the first two numbers I haven't been able to verify what they are. My guess is that they are a reference to possibly the schema and the table, but I can't find anything that tells me one way or another. [The Postgres manual entry](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/infoschema-table-constraints.html) on this isn't very useful in this regard.

So what are the first two numbers then? How can I tie these numbers to pertinent information?

Comment: What's the context for this? i.e. What are you looking to accomplish with this information?

Comment: I've been working on some plpgsql functions for essentially copying certain constraints from one table to another. I've already figured out everything that I need to do that, though (got all the info I needed for that through joining it with the information_schema.check_constraints). This is more because I just want to know what it is and how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres stores its information about tables, types, columns, constraints, etc. in the `pg_catalog` schema.

The top level is `namespace`.  In your example above, the 2200 refers to the namespace.  You can see this by evaluating:

   `select oid,* from pg_catalog.pg_namespace where oid=2200;`

The second number from your example above (77911989) refers to the oid (object id) of the table.  You can see the related information with:

   `select oid,* from pg_catalog.pg_class where oid=77911989;`

The third number (1) refers to the column number within the table.  You can see the relevant information by using:

   `select * from pg_catalog.pg_attribute where attrelid=77911989 and attnum=1;`

Many of the returned values (like `atttypmod`) are OIDs to other tables (like `pg_type`) in the `pg_catalog` schema.

Comment: I know this is a rather old thread, but, @Robert , we're not worthy... Quick question for you: can we assume that the same thought process is valid for other unnamed constraints and indexes?